# iQuery ajax request returns empty $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm creating a table containing a list of uploaded files and I wanted to add a link in the last column to allow the user to delete the corresponding file. I could simply use a link "delete.php?fileid=", but I prefer to use a POST request and so I decided to use a form with the ID of the file in the database being passed as hidden input.

**Issue**: console.log($(this).closest('form').find(":input").serialize()); returns an empty string. Can you help understanding what is the root cause?

Code of form submission:

```
$('.f-delete a'). click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this).closest('form').find(":input").serialize());
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'delete_image.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: $(this).closest('form').find(":input").serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Error: Could not delete the file');
            }  
        });
    });
```

The markup:

```
<table class="table table-striped"> 
  <thead> 
    <tr> 
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test file</td>
      <td>image/png</td>
      <td>302.65 KB</td>
      <td>
        <form id="f-1" class="f-delete" method="post" action="delete_image.php">
          <input id="id-1" value="1" type="hidden">
          <a id="a-1" href="">Delete image</a>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test file 2</td>
      <td>image/png</td>
      <td>37.88 KB</td>
      <td>
        <form id="f-2" class="f-delete" method="post" action="delete_image.php">
            <input id="id-2" value="2" type="hidden">
            <a id="a-2" href="">Delete image</a>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>                   
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: And did you try the obvious, console logging `$(this).closest('form').find(":input").serialize()` to see that you actually have data ?

Comment: Also note that you're expecting JSON to be returned, anything else would fail.

Comment: please, post the delete_image.php code too

Comment: It's returning an empty string.

Comment: And now you know what the problem is, you can't serialize elements that don't have a `name` attribute, as that would be required to create the querystring `name=value` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your html, for use `serialize` your input's should have name. For example:

```
 <input id="id-1" value="1" name="id-1" type="hidden">
```

For serialize use

```
 $(this).closest('form').serialize() //return id-1=1
```

Result https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/1Lv8gkms/